# Dropzone list of files

Tags: javascript, forms, dropzone.js

How can I get list of all (which has been loaded, canceled, is in the process etc.) files from DropZone? I'm going to parse this data and generate hidden input field before form will be submitted.

Comment: I have found out, that `console.log(Dropzone.instances[0].files);` returns correct data. But how can I get the same data with specific dropzone_id not by weird `instanes[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too in the past so ive added my own list into it:

In the complete-event Ive created a created a list in this form

```
this.list = {}; //this is not inside the event if this would be inside the list has max one item so you have to do that as a normal var in your js
// response text is a hashed filename so its unique you also can use a normal array and push it
this.list[file.xhr.responseText] = file.name
```

But you also have to remove file in list on remove (In the removed event):

```
delete this.list[file.xhr.responseText];
```

Than you can add a save function which writes this list into the hidden input field

```
 $('#hiddenfield').attr('value', JSON.stringify(dropzone.list));
```